# Migration com campos personalizados no Laravel

Tags: laravel, migrations

Acostumado com as facilidades do migration existentes no Asp.net MVC, tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Existe forma de criar fields em minha Model e ao executar o Migration o framework automaticamente criar esses campos em meu método Up?
Na documentação e tutoriais que vejo, sempre é necessário alterar a classe de migration e inserir os campos manualmente.

No Asp.net MVC o migration automaticamente cria os campos conforme minha classe Model.

É possível isso no Laravel?

Exemplo, classe com campos "Nome, Telefone". O metodo Up automaticamente criaria o

```
$table->string('nome'); $table->string('telefone');
```

Comment: Não porque em PHP você não precisa declarar os campos de antemão.

Comment: Poxa, que pena, sentirei saudades disso! Mas muito obrigado pela resposta @LINQ